# included cpufreq.h but shows linker error in linux c++

Tags: linux, g++, linker-errors, undefined-reference

My problem is I am getting an undefined reference error in linux g++

`cpufreq.h` is in `usr/include` directory and I included `#include <cpufreq.h>`. This has declaration for `cpufreq_get_freq_kernel()`

But when I call `cpufreq_get_freq_kernel()`, it gets a linker error:

```
undefined reference to `cpufreq_get_freq_kernel'
```

I am using netbeans to compile the program.

Any solution?

Comment: Please show us, how g++ and ld (linker) was called. Seems there is some problem with your  libcpufreq library, e.g. it just not passed to g++

Comment: Can you show your syntax for the call with the passed in value? It always returned zero for me.  Had to fopen /sys/devices/../cpu0/cpufrequency/.. in order to get the value.

Answer (score 2):

Including headers is not usually enough, you also need to link to the library, which is probably done by adding  `-lcpufreq` to your linker command.